# Blank chart using Google Chart API

Tags: json, charts, google-visualization

I am currently using the following JSON to generate a chart using Google Chart API:

```
{
"cols":[
    {
        "id":"DateOfBirth",
        "label":"Date of Birth",
        "type":"string"
    },
    {
        "id":"Number",
        "label":"Number",
        "type":"number"
    },
    {
        "id":"Gender",
        "label":"Gender",
        "type":"string"
    }
],
"rows":[
    {
        "c":[
            {
            "v":"F"
            },
            {
            "v":"2012-08-07"
            },
            {
            "v":"1"
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "c":[
            {
            "v":"M"
            },
            {
            "v":"1988-07-28"
            },
            {
            "v":"1"
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "c":[
            {
            "v":"F"
            },
            {
            "v":"1990-05-05"
            },
            {
            "v":"1"
            }
        ]
    }
]
}
```

However, the chart does not show (it only shows up as a white canvas with the caption). I cannot figure out what is the issue with my JSON. I have also included the code used to render the chart:

```
// where json is the string literal
function drawChart(json) {
    // Create the data table.
    var data = new google.visualization.DataTable(json);

    // Set chart options
    var options = {'title':'Students',
        'width':400,
        'height':300,
        'view': {'columns': [0,2]}};

    // Instantiate and draw our chart, passing in some options.
    var chart = new google.visualization.PieChart($('#chart_div')[0]);
    chart.draw(data, options);
}
```

...and I piece everything together with an AJAX call.

```
$(function() {
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: localUrl,
        success: function(data)
        {
            drawChart(data);
        }
    });
});

google.load('visualization', '1.0', {'packages':['corechart']});
```

I'm not too sure where have I gone wrong. Can anybody help me out?

Comment: can you provide a jsfiddle please ?

Comment: Have tried my best, http://jsfiddle.net/HUMyS/6/, unfortunately 'Container is not defined' shows up... this did not happen in local development.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The values of your "number" column should not be strings:

```
'{"cols":[{"id":"Gender","label":"Gender","type":"string"},{"id":"DateOfBirth","label":"Date of Birth","type":"string"},{"id":"Number","label":"Number","type":"number"}],"rows":[{"c":[{"v":"F"},{"v":"1988-08-10"},{"v":1}]},{"c":[{"v":"M"},{"v":"1988-07-28"},{"v":1}]},{"c":[{"v":"F"},{"v":"1988-08-10"},{"v":1}]}]}'
```

You can try this in a Google playground for the [Table](https://code.google.com/apis/ajax/playground/?type=visualization#table). If you want to have a [PieChart](https://code.google.com/apis/ajax/playground/?type=visualization#pie_chart), 3 columns won't work; removing the 'DateOfBirth' column is working then:

```
'{"cols":[{"id":"Gender","label":"Gender","type":"string"},{"id":"Number","label":"Number","type":"number"}],"rows":[{"c":[{"v":"F"},{"v":1}]},{"c":[{"v":"M"},{"v":1}]},{"c":[{"v":"F"},{"v":1}]}]}'
```

Comment: 3 columns won't work is right; I got it to function using just 2 columns.